# How do I Validate the File Type of a File Upload in case of multiple file uploads in one go?

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, logic

My requirement is to upload multiple jpeg file in one go, the problem is when some one uploads any other extension file along with jpeg, in this case the alert comes after file reaches to server i.e., have 15mb mp3 file, if we upload it, error comes after 15mb data transfer to server...

Is there anything I could do to check file extension before actual data transfer.
I m using cake php.

Appreciating your help and support.

Comment: ya, in the PHP before you call your upload function, take the $_FILE['name'] and do your checks before sending them over. take a look at this class, it does alot and makes it easy to validate before uplaoding: http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm

Comment: @Eli I think he means sending to server by upload. And for checking in php the file has to be send to server.

Comment: oh, I thought he wanted to check before large data is sent over causing a lag before the security checks.

Answer (score 0):

You would only be able to achieve this with client side scripting if you want to trap the file format BEFORE the submission of data if this is a standard HTML form that has been generated with Cake. This is because the HTML form and browser are handling the data posting.

It is true that you could invoke some sophisticated PHP WITH scripting to do extension checking but it is probably not necessary here, you need scripting regardless to react to your "submit" button being pressed by the user

Have a look at the jQuery Validation plugin, and notably its "Accept" attribute [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept) for example or use a simple custom built JS extension checker.

```
$("#myform").validate({
   rules: {
   myfield: {
     required: true,
     accept: "jpg"
}
```

}
});